# not able to call child class method twice in parent js file

Tags: javascript, class, inheritance

I have a category dropdown(in parent js) whose subcategory fills on parent page load as well on dropdown change . subcategory will fill from child js  method .I have to create child js instance twice . on page load and on dropdown down change.

I dont want to create object  in document.ready or as global variable

where should i create child class object exactly so that it can be used all over ?

problem is that jquery not letting me call

```
 $.getScript('../Reports/assets/js/BookingReports.js'
```

twice as it send error that child class name(BookingReports) identifier as already created .

```
class ReportsInterface extends ReportBase { 
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.fillSubCategory;
    }

    init() {
        this.Categories();  
    }

    Categories() {
        //fill category 
        this.FillSubCategory(); 
    }

    FillSubCategory() {
        if(!this.fillSubCategory) {
            $.getScript(
                '../Reports/assets/js/BookingReports.js',
                function() {
                    this.fillSubCategory=new FillSubCategory("1");
                    obj.GetSubCategory();
                }
            )
        }
    }
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#ddlcategory").on('change', function() {
        (new ReportsInterface()).showReportBooking();
    })
})
```

i also tried to save object in parent class property but .cannot use it as object later on. how can I call child class method twice without creating any global variable ?

Answer (score 2):

If you are using ES6, I would recommend not using JQuery to import separate files but rather using the [ES6 import/export syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import).

I imagine the issue is that since `$.getScript` makes an http request to redownload the script file, it is actually running the script file twice (one for each download); in the second download, it will run into the naming conflict. ES6 import/exports would solve this issue for you, preventing BookingReport from being redefined.

You should be aware of a couple of things however:

(1) Using your JQuery setup, you get the benefit of lazy loading. To get the same in ES6, you'd have to use the slightly more complicated dynamic imports (see that same link above) -- for this app, however, it doesn't really look like you'd need that.

(2) You might want to familiarize yourself with a bundler like [Webpack](https://webpack.js.org/) as this will do ahead-of-time importing and leave you with a single file to download rather than having to ping-pong back and forth from the server as you try to download all of the modularized files.

Comment: Yes. You would have to do something like ```export BookingReport;``` in your ```BookingReports.js``` file and then ```import BookingReport from '../Reports/assets/js/BookingReports.js'``` at the top of the file you posted. Note: I would really recommend using a bundler to ensure cross-browser compatibility (but if you are just making a proof-of-concept on the latest browser, then you are probably fine).